# Counting the direct children of a ul, excluding a script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my HTML structure which includes script tag

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="main.js"></script>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Following is my JS code to get the length of direct child

```
var directChild =  document.getElementById('list').children;
console.log(directChild.length); // this gives me length as 5
```

Comment: `$('ul').find('li').length`?

Comment: Why is there a `script` tag even in there? It will mean your HTML is invalid.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b8e4uqvx/

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for your reply .I want a custom selector which should count direct child of any type within a container. For that I tried using document.querySelectorAll("#list > *") but it is counting that  script tag

Comment: @Rory Yes It is invalid html but I need to use due to some reasons within html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in reading the count of the `<li>` child elements which are *fathered* by the element with id *list* I guess this is as close as you'd get to doing it w/ vanilla javascript...

```
var liElements = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName("li"); 
alert(liElements.length);
```

However I'd also strongly advise you (as many others have already advised you) to look into using [jquery](https://jquery.com/) for DOM manipulation instead of plain old javascript...

If you want all the child elements WITHOUT any `<script>` tag elements this could come in handy (it doesn't filter `<script>` tags but it comes close by filtering out tags with the specific `type` attribute `text/javascript` which is used only by `<script>` tags ;))

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#list > *:not([type="text/javascript"])');
alert(nodes.length);
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: Actually I have developed one utility with javascript where i cant use jquery . Developers of my team are using my utility at various places so i cant use a specific selector like Ul > Li . I added the above code just to demonstrate where i am facing the problem because i cant put the original code here

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what exactly is it that you are you looking for in this case? A way of being able to select all direct children of an element regardless of their type WITH the exception of tag <script> elements?

Comment: yes exactly i want the same one over here. I dont want that script tag to be counted

Comment: Thank you very much Filip for your help. It has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just move your script tag out of the `<ul>`. It will make your code valid, more sensible, and will make it do what you want.

I acknowledge that if you are so insistent as to leave a `<script>` tag in a `<ul>` then the comment from @Pekka will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Because script tag is #list's child element.

Comment: @Hems is aware of this aspect and thus the question; this answer is not helpful with regard to his actual question.